# Access Y value in Windows Forms Chart at specific X location

Tags: c++, winforms

I have a chart that plots some experimental values in a Windows Forms Project.

I want to access a specific X index and see what the Y value is at that point. How do I do this? I found methods to search for index using the Y value, but I kind of need the opposite.

Another question ([Get Y value across .NET chart series from X value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15565722/get-y-value-across-net-chart-series-from-x-value)) talks about looking up value from Series["blah"] -> Points, but I can't find a method that does so.

I'd appreciate any assistance.

Comment: It is just a chart control, not a spreadsheet.  You supply the data for the series, you can find it back from that same data.

Comment: You propose I keep a huge buffer that holds a copy of the plot? I supply the data that arrives at random intervals in time. If I can remove points or look for Min&Max, I would expect there to be a way to find a point of interest.